# How to discover if some day is a workday

Tags: date, language-agnostic

Is there some library, pattern or common way deal with workdays? I mean, is there some relatively well adopted way to know if some day is a workday and not weekend, holiday etc.?

Also, supposing there is such thing, would it be helpful to discover if the day has some "detail"? For example, here in Brazil we use to work only in the afternoon of the Ash Wednesday. Is there some kind of flexible framework for dealing with such variations?

I could implement this kind of business logic without any difficulty but I would not like to reinvent the wheel and other users suggestions can be helpful. Also, it seems a very recurrent problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on your location, too - is a Friday a workday or not?? Sunday??

Comment: @marc_s here only Saturday and Sunday are weekend days. Actually, I am amazed that this is not the case worldwide :) I would say a good answer would be flexible enough to deal with both cases. Anyway, it is easy to deal with weekends; the interesting part is to deal with holidays.

Comment: Some Middle East countries have Friday off but work on Sunday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are into Java programming you can use this :
[Non-working day and Holiday Handler Algorithms](http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I am not working with Java in the project in question... However, I really, really love this lib! Thank you! Sure it will be useful and I bet I can get inspired by its architectural decisions.

Answer (score 2):

Most people I know use a `calendar table` for this kind of thing. My table contains info for 80+ countries

Comment: In fact, that is the solution I am likely to use.

Comment: Have fun maintaining that database! :)

Comment: @MikeEast....The beautiful part is that I don't maintain it, the operations team does  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Google has some calendars that you probably can use.

Check this out for instance: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.brazilian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic

You have to use your Google account to browse them and there might be some license limitations on the usage, but the information is there.

Comment: I thought about it and it seems to be a good idea to use it. There are some extra problems to solve, however. For example, here we have state and municipality holidays, it is usual to "move" a holiday from Thursday to Friday, it is not rare to "hang up" a Friday between a holiday and Saturday, dispensing the employees etc. etc. I am thinking about a mixed solution using some extern data source and a database table and looking for eventual tools or patterns to help in this implementation.